# How can I limit bandwidth on a public network?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, bandwidth, bandwidth-control, torrent

Our workplace has a public network where people often connect with their personal laptops. A sizeable number of users are torrenting which is killing bandwidth for the rest of the network's users.

At this time, a policy solution of 'no torrenting' is infeasible so a technical solution is preferable.

Is there way of limiting bandwidth usage of all users?

And, if there are solutions, is there a software solution for Windows Server 2008?

Comment: > a policy solution of 'no torrenting' is infeasible

Why? Danger of being sacked of punished is an effective deterrent of unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> At this time, a policy solution of 'no torrenting' is infeasible

Fire manager, put sane manager in place. You can not find a technical problem for what is essentially a legal compliance issue.

> And, if there are solutions, is there a software solution for Windows Server 2008?

Yes, there are. No, not for 2008. Not for pretty much any server - this is stuff that is generally handled by a firwall. And even there...

...You ONLY can SENSIBLE limit egress bandwidth (i.e. data LEAVING the company) as you have no real control over INGRESS (i.e. data coming in). If ysome protovol is flooding you with incoming data, your firewall is the first place to see it, which is too late.

Egress is trivial and any decent router with QOS and queueing functionality can handle this. Mikrotik, as well as just a custom Linux box.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wish I had the authority to do some firing. It's not so much managers disallowing the policy, it's more that I have no authority to enforce the policy beyond identifying who's doing it and asking them politely not to.